# Issue with Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, fileinputstream, objectinputstream

I have a method in my program that reads from a file, and I have associated with both a FileInputStream variable and an ObjectInputStream variable. However, I do not know how many objects will be serialized in the file when I run the program, so I do not know how many objects to deserialize using the method readObject(). This is the method from my project:

```
public void importResults(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    TestEntry entry = null;
    try(FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file)) {
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        tests.clear();

        entry = (TestEntry)ois.readObject();

        tests.add(entry);

        ois.close();
    }
}
```

The variable entry is where I will store TestEntry objects that I deserialize from the file. The problem is, if I try to deserialize too many objects, I get an EOFException. How do I get my program to figure out how many objects there are serialized in the file so I can deserialized the right amount? Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace for the exception you get?

Comment: Just catch EOFException from readObject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just read in a loop until you get `EOFException,` which is thrown when there are no more objects to read.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that your program stopped completely once an exception was thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a way to count how many Objects are serialized since one file can only hold one Object. You are probably getting EOFException because you are doing something like below. Since there is only one Object in a file no matter how many you serialize, reading twice from the same Stream will result in EOFException.

```
in.readObject();
in.readObject();
```

I just tested and you can read an Object any number of times from the same file as long as you don't do the above or something similar.

My test is below

```
public static void main(String []args) {
     writeObject(new Integer(333));
     for(int i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
         Integer i = (Integer)readObject();
         System.out.println(i);//prints 333
     }
}
public static void writeObject(Object obj) {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("file.dat"));
        out.writeObject(obj);
        out.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e) {}
}
public static Object readObject() {
    Object obj = null;
    try {
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("file.dat"));

        obj = in.readObject();
        in.close();
    }
    catch(IOException e){}
    catch(ClassNotFoundException e){}
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could write the number of objects that are present in the file and for the deserialization first read that number (however I am not sure if one file can contain multiple serialized objects).

However if you put your objects in an `ArrayList` that you serialize, you can write that `ArrayList` to the file and deserialize it just by reading **one** object.

I made a test class `A` and this works :

```
public class A implements Serializable {
    int a, b, c;
} 

public static ArrayList<A> deserializeObjects(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    FileInputStream fIn = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream oIn = new ObjectInputStream (fIn);
    ArrayList<A> objects = null;

    // Read array of objects
    if(fIn.available() > 0) {
        objects = (ArrayList<A>) oIn.readObject();
    }

    oIn.close();
    fIn.close();

    return objects;
}

public static void serializeObjects(File file, ArrayList<A> objects) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
    ObjectOutputStream oOut = new ObjectOutputStream(fOut);

    // Write the whole arraylist to file
    oOut.writeObject(objects);
    oOut.flush();
    oOut.close();
    fOut.close();
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // Make test objects
    A o1 = new A();
    A o2 = new A();

    o1.a = 1; o1.b = 2; o1.c = 3;
    o2.a = 4; o2.b = 5; o2.c = 6;

    ArrayList<A> objects = new ArrayList<A>();
    objects.add(o1);
    objects.add(o2);

    File f = new File("yourFile");
    f.createNewFile();

    serializeObjects(f, objects); // Serialize arraylist
    ArrayList<A> deserialized = deserializeObjects(f); // Deserialize it

    // Success??
    System.out.println("a : " + deserialized.get(0).a + ", b : " + deserialized.get(0).b + ", c : " + deserialized.get(0).c);
    System.out.println("a : " + deserialized.get(1).a + ", b : " + deserialized.get(1).b + ", c : " + deserialized.get(1).c);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the object to a List and serialize/deserialize that list.

```
    // entry = (TestEntry)ois.readObject();
    List<TestEntry> entries = (List<TestEntry>)ois.readObject();
```